# Why has my rankings suddenly dropped on google?

Tags: seo, ranking

I've managed to optimized one of my websites to rank 2nd on the first page for the search term I wanted it to rank well for and quite often I go and check to see if the rankings are still the same or if they have changed.

Yesterday I went to check and I see my website's not even on the first page! I thought that was odd, so I decided to do a quick search via both my mobile phones and my website is ranking normally (2nd on the 1st page).

So why is it that when I use 2 different mobile phones to do the search, my website is there and ranked normally as expected whereas on my desktop pc, my website has dropped off the first page (disappeared)?

WTF is going on? This doesn't make any sense! The only difference I can think of between my mobile phones and desktop PC is their IP address but how could that possibly effect rankings?

Just so you know, I don't do any dodgy backlinking strategies. In fact I don't even do any backlinking strategies to begin with!

** UPDATE **

So I quickly did a search on my desktop PC now and suddenly my website re-appeared back to 2nd on the first page. I then refreshed the google search and my website has disappeared again!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [SEO](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi Rowland - I think my page-rank-freakout must have made me lose all focus, lol.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been two recent Google updates, Panda 4.1 targeting thin and low quality content, and some updates fighting private blog networks (PBNs).

If you have content quality issues, fix them and it will help with rankings. If you benefit from backlinks from PBNs, remove them or disavow them A.S.A.P.

As usual, every updates often provokes the [Google Dance](https://ligatures.net/content/expertise/introduction-to-seo-concepts.html#GOOGLE_DANCE) (link to personal post). This could explain what you are observing too.

**REM:** Since this question is SEO related it should be posted in [Pro Webmaster](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) (at least you know for next time).

Comment: Thanks buddy I appreciate the answer and insight information :) Very interesting! You know what, I'm very happy Google has slammed PBNs for backlinking because I've always been against it merely because it's all done to manipulate the algorithms which is wrong! I'm surprised Google has taken this long to take action! Nevertheless, I clearly don't participate in in PBNs (because I simply don't have the time to do so), so I think you're quite correct in saying that it could have been the 'Google Dance' because my rankings is back to normal and isn't 'dancing' per se ...

Comment: ... I do however have other websites that link back to my main website though I've made sure I've put rel="nofollow" so that they don't count as manipulated juice. Would you say that's still naughty or playing it safe? My main website has quality content (took me months of research to create it) so I feel I've earned the high ranking though my other pages are lacking page rank (when other websites that are hardly related to the search term rank higher) which I don't understand and trying to get my head around. I also think that because I haven't fixed URL Canonicalisation it's ...

Comment: ... hurting my websites rankings and pages within sub directories! My windows 2003 iis server is making this fix very difficult and I'm trying to organize a linux server to make this fix easy!

Comment: nofollow links cannot hurt you, so you are safe from this angle. If you only have a couple of those links, it won't hurt if they are dofollow. It only hurts when you have tons stuffed with anchor text keywords for example. Regarding canonicalization, you don't need a new server, you only need to add canonical links in your HTML.